# React JS: doesn't state gets its initial value after rerender?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

When the state is changed, the function runs again(correct me if I'm wrong). And because first line of App function defines state, the values of data and setData won't be default again?
For example,

```
import { useState } from "react";
import './App.css';

function App() {
  let [data, setData] = useState("string");
  function update() {
    setData("changed")
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 onClick={update}>{data}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

the state default value is used only on the first render, subsequent state updates will make your component use the updated state value.

in your example the default value of state variable `data` which is `string` will be used on initial render.

if you click on `h1` tag the `data` value becomes `changed` which will be used onward.

[codesnadbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-bhabha-25gt4?file=/src/App.js)